# jQuery method chaining on multiple element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are severeal elements with the css class `pageLink`
I would like to replace some strings within these links

```
 $(".pageLink").html($(".pageLink").html().replace("x", "y"));
```

The problem is, the second `$(".pageLink").html()` gets the inner HTML of any of the elements and not necessarily the html of the element that I'm about to change/set. I would need something like

```
 $(".pageLink").html(this.html().replace("x", "y"));
```

Does something like that exist in jQuery, or do I have to use a `each` loop?

Comment: what is the control or element you about to replace the text which class is .pagelink?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `each` to loop over all the elements. You can use function to set the innerHTML of the element.

```
$(".pageLink").html(function(ind, elHtml) {
    return elHtml.replace("x", "y");
});
```

[*Docs*](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a selection set and you want to match each element against itself you need to use an `each` loop or a similar looping construct in the setter, no clever way around that since you need a function scope in order for `this` to work as in your exmaple:

```
$(".pageLink").html(function(_, v){
    return v.replace("x", "y");
});
```

Comment: @Balachandran well, I didn't know that - so that's probably why :) I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each)

```
$('.pagelink').each(function(){
   $(this).html(function(i,v){
     return v.replace("x", "y");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate through the elements and apply the HTML to each link individually.

```
$(".pageLink").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("x", "y"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Get innnerHtml value as a argument in callback function,

```
$(".pageLink").html(function (idx, elm) {
    return elm.replace("x", "y")
});
```